# Replace lockscreen app windows universal app 10

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, lockscreen

I was wondering how would it be possible to dev an app to replace the default lockscreen on windows 10 universal apps. I know that there was some kind of apps in windows 8.0/8.1 but I've never seen this on w10. Is it possible? and how?

(Such as [Tetra lockscreen](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-garage-launches-bunch-new-windows-phone-apps))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build an app such as "Tetra lockscreen" or "Live Lock Screen Beta", which provide additional functionality directly on the lockscreen, **this is not possible** as the makers of those apps have additionall access to private APIs normal devs have no access to. Also, both apps aren't available any more as far as I can see, probably the private APIs have been removed with Windows 10.

If you simply want to change the lockscreen picture, **this is possible** with the [UserProfilePersonalizationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class which provides the functions [TrySetLockScreenImageAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetlockscreenimageasync.aspx) and [TrySetWallpaperImageAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetwallpaperimageasync.aspx). With the [IsSupported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.issupported.aspx) you can check if the Windows device is able to change its lockscreen. On Desktop and Mobile the function currently returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks, but as i can understand, it 'only' set an image background, would it be possible to add such a button or something like this?

Comment: Adding a button to the lockscreen? No - but this also wasn't possible with Windows 8.0/8.1

Comment: no, look at this tetra lockscreen app
http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-garage-launches-bunch-new-windows-phone-apps

Comment: @SvenBorden This app was released by Microsoft who have additional access to APIs normal devs do not have unfortunately. As far as I know, there are no public APIs do to such things

Comment: @tipa if you took the informations from the original link, then please also keep the link.

Comment: The original link is still there (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings)